# Lucene 3.6.2 does not contain TopDocCollector class

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, lucene

I am trying my hands on the lucene example from the following link http://www.hascode.com/2010/03/how-to-build-a-quick-lucene-search/

however, I am not using maven , just the lucene 3.6.2 library imported into the NetBeans project library

but the followiing code gets NetBeans complaining :

```
 // searching ...
    int hitsPerPage = 10;
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index);
    TopDocCollector collector = new TopDocCollector(hitsPerPage);
    searcher.search(q, collector);
    ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

the IDE complains it cannot find class TopDocCollector

I have imported the following package

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocCollector;
```

as shown in the tutorials but looks like it is not contained in the libbrary

please any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you download [lucene-3.6.2.zip](http://apache.mirrors.timporter.net/lucene/java/3.6.2/), it contains `lucene-core-3.6.2.jar`. This jar definitely contains `org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocsCollector.class`.

Comment: I have downloaded the 3.6.2 zip package and have imported the jar files into the project a indicated in the following object=org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.classpath.ClassPathSupport$RelativePath@396f3fdf, broken=false, additional={}
artifactURI=null, type=0, property=${file.reference.lucene-core-3.6.2.jar}

Comment: I have rather used the TopDocs class from the lucene library which works fine don't know whether the TopDocCollector has been deprecated